# Using a loop to delete first row from files in R

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to figure out how to remove the first row from every output file that is created from my code. There are 50 of these .txt files and they named after each state abbreviation.

To remove the first row, I've tried using this code in the for loop I have:

```
out[[i]] <- out[[i]][-1,]
```

without much success so far.

This is the code I'm using the create the 50 files named after state abbreviations.

```
setwd("/Users/Tim/Downloads/All_Geographies")

statelist = c('ak','al','ar','az','ca','co','ct','de','fl','ga','hi','ia','id','il','in','ks','ky','la','ma','md','me','mi','mn','mo','ms','mt','nc','nd','ne','nh','nj','nm','nv','ny','oh','ok','or','pa','ri','sc','sd','tn','tx','ut','va','vt','wa','wi','wv','wy')

out <- vector('list', length(statelist))
for (i in seq_along(statelist)){
  file_names <- list.files(getwd())
  file_names <- file_names[grepl(paste0("e20171", statelist[i], 
              "0001000.txt"),file_names)]
  files <-  lapply(file_names, read.csv, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   out[[i]] <- do.call(rbind, files)
}

newfilenames <- paste0(letters[seq_along(out)], ".txt")
lapply(seq_along(out), function(i) write.table(out[[i]],
      file = statelist[i], quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t"))
```

This code runs perfectly and it correctly output 50 files that are named after the state abbreviations. I just need to remove the first row in each of these 50 files.

Comment: Try `write.table(out[[i]][-1, , drop = FALSE], etc`.

Comment: `system2("sed", c("-i", "-e", "1d", shQuote(out)))` (you have `sed` if you are not windows or if you have RTools installed).